# Error: Could not find or load main class MainKt

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea, kotlin-multiplatform

In Multiplatform project, I want to use main function inside `jvmMain` to test the library I’m working on, but when I’m trying to run this it returns an error `Error: Could not find or load main class MainKt for following function in Main.kt`

```
fun main() {
    println("Hello World!")
}
```

I've got `Main.kt` file in a root directory of my module, but putting it under some package is also throwing this error.

I'm using Java 8 JDK:
[image]

Are there any additional steps I should make to be able to use `main` function?

EDIT:
I did additional checks and I found out that when in the project I have `android` target then in the `jvm`  main function I’m getting this error above. When I’m creating a new project with exactly the same configuration, but without `android` target it’s working properly, main function compiles and it is printing a message.
Any guess what is causing this problem?

Comment: not sure that this can be debugged without a sample project or at least more information of how it is set-up.

Comment: It's a standard project configuration I created from IntelliJ template. I added android, iOS, JS and JVM targets.
I also edited a original post and added the information that I'm getting this error only when there is the `android` target added to the Multiplatform project

Comment: Hello, @user3448282, see the related issue at the Kotlin tracker here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-42486